# Knight of the Isles

Tags: chess, mazes

Today the Knight of the Isles must cross the archipelago to get to the castle.

The knight is at the bottom left, the castle at the top right.  The green squares are islands of grass, the blue squares are water you better don't fall into.

The knight's horse could easy jump from island to island.  But this is its first outing with a real knight.  And he has learned that knights move according to very strict rules on a chessboard  So it insists on showing he knows "the proper manners".

So the knight is a bit embarrassed.  The horse sometimes jumps, sometimes refuses to jump making the whole crossing a messy business.

Can you help the knight to guide the horse through the archipelago to the castle?

To summarize, you have to bring the knight from the bottom left to the top right, jumping from green square to green square, doing only valid chess knight moves.

[image: large square full of random green and blue squares]

This is my own creation

While I thought this is an original idea, at the time of posting this SE presents me with two very similar questions.  So the idea is not new but the puzzle is.  I hope you enjoy it anyway.

Comment: Someone made a webgame in a very similar premise to this puzzle on Kongregate right before Kongregate stopped taking new games. https://www.kongregate.com/games/FractalSunrise/knight-errant. Not the same puzzle obviously, but it explores a lot of the same mechanics, like how a knight can't change parity if they're on a 2-by-x island.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

> [image]

> Took me around 20 mins. Thankfully every time you have multiple choices from the same cell, you reach a dead end soon enough. My approach was to go with one of the choices every time but mark which cell I last diverged from. If I hit a dead end, keep hitting undo and then go with the next choice.

Comment: Happy to see it was solved by good old neurons, not by silicon.